# C program why the value of "a" also changed

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    int a[3][3] = { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 }, { 7, 8, 9 } };
    int *b  = a[1];
    b[2] = 99;
    for ( int i = 0; i < 3; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%d,", a[1][i] );
    }
}
```

**ouput is** ：4,5,99,

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
        int     a[3]    = { 1, 2, 3 };
        int     b       = a[1];
        b = 99;
        for ( int i = 0; i < 3; i++ )
        {
                printf( "%d,", a[i] );
        }
}
```

**output is** ：1,2,3

why I got such different results?
i thought in the first part a should also stay unchanged

Comment: Do you even understand the written code? or are you asking for: why `int *` behaves different from `int`?

Comment: read about pointers. a lot.

Answer (score 4):

When `int *b = a[1]` executes, `b` is pointing to the *same memory location* as `a[1]`, i.e. an `int[3]`. Thus, when you update `b[2]`, `a[1][2]` is also updated.

In the second case, `int b = a[1]` sets `b` to be the same *value* as `a[1]`, but at a different memory location, so when `b` is updated, `a` is not.

I would read up more about how pointers work in C.

Answer (score 1):

```
int *b
```

b is  a pointer which points to the second row of your 2D array and it has the memory location of the row `a[1]` and it can change the contents of the memory location by dereferencing it.

```
b[2] = *(b+2) = 99;
```

Whereas

```
int b;
```

b is not a pointer. You can't reference a variable like a pointer to store value in particular memory location. Hence you see that the value is not changed when you do

```
b = 99;
```

in the second code snippet

Answer (score 1):

**NOTE:** Here the int is assumed to be 2 bytes.

**case 1**:
    int a[3][3] = { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 }, { 7, 8, 9 } };

Will be allocated as follows:

```
a[0]:

a[0][0] a[0][1] a[0][2]
+----+----+----+
| 1  | 2  | 3  |
+----+----+----+
 1000 1002 1004

a[1]:

a[1][0] a[1][1] a[1][2]
+----+----+----+
| 4  | 5  |  6 | 
+----+----+----+
 1006 1008 1010

a[2]:

a[2][0] a[2][1] a[2][2]   
+----+----+----+
|  7 |  8 |  9 |
+----+----+----+
 1012 1014 1016

int *b  = a[1];

  b
+----+
|1006| // 1006 is the address of the a[1] 
+----+
 11000

b[2] = 99;
```

b[2] is the third element in the second array which has address location 1010 .

since b is a pointer to an second(i.e, a[1]) array and hence b[2] is nothing but *(b+2) its as offset from the first element and therefore a[1][2] will get afftected.

```
  b
+----+
|1006| // 1006+2 will be the location that is 1010 (as int takes 2 bytes). Here 
+----+ // address location are taken for just reference purpose.
 11000

a[1]:

a[1][0] a[1][1] a[1][2]
+----+----+----+
| 4  | 5  | 22 | 
+----+----+----+
 1006 1008 1010

printf( "%d,", a[1][i] );

Outputs: 4,5,99
```

**case 2** :

```
int a[3] = { 1, 2, 3 };

a[3]:

 a[0] a[1] a[2]
+----+----+----+
| 1  | 2  | 3  |
+----+----+----+
 1000 1002 1004

int b = a[1];

  b
+----+
| 2  |
+----+
 5000

b = 99;
```

The value of b gets overwritten.

```
  b
+----+
| 99 | // Since b is a normal variable and hence will not affect array memory location.
+----+
 5000

 printf( "%d,", a[i] );
```

As you can see the array does not got affected.

```
 Output: 1,2,3
```